# How to put a byte string into a float in IDL

Tags: floating-point, byte, analysis, primitive-types, idl-programming-language

I am new to the programming language IDL (Interactive Data Language) and am learning to code in it. I'd like to know how to put a byte string into a float in IDL without saving it to a file.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the float routine, i.e., float('5') is 5.0.

Comment: I'll definitely try this! Thanks! :)